# How to add a querystring into BigCommerce code?

Tags: php, bigcommerce

How can I add a querystring to right after "image=product.main_image" directive. I just want to add a querystring to the SRC tag of the image but I don't know how to edit BigCommerce code. Thank you.

```
    {{> components/common/responsive-img
                image=product.main_image
                class="productView-image--default"
                fallback_size=theme_settings.product_size
                lazyload=theme_settings.lazyload_mode
                default_image=theme_settings.default_image_product
                otherAttributes="data-main-image"
    }}
```

Comment: Why do you need to add a query param? There might be another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main_image property here is actually an object, with the URL nested within. So you can't add a query string directly to it.

You could do that within the component itself, such as here:

https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/templates/components/common/responsive-img.html#L39

Where you could invoke the [`{{setURLQueryParam}}` helper](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference) on top of the result to add the parameter if you like.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out my self. Thanks.